# Spivak's proof of $a\cdot 0 = 0$

Tags: real-numbers, axioms

I picked up Spivak's *Calculus (3rd Edition)* today and it seemed like a good idea to go through the section *Basic Properties of Numbers*. In this chapter, Spivak proves that

$$a \cdot 0 = 0$$

The proof looks simple:

$$a \cdot 0 + a \centerdot 0 = a \centerdot (0+0) = a \centerdot 0$$

My question is just as simple: How do I get from $a \centerdot 0 = 0$ to $a \centerdot 0 + a \centerdot 0 = a \centerdot (0+0)$?

Comment: I think you asked your question backwards.  Spivak's proof involves two equalities.  The first follows by the property $a b + a c = a(b+c)$.  The second follows since by definition of $0$, $0+x = x$.

Comment: You're both right. I'm a proof noob. :) Cheers!

Comment: He does _not_ go from $a\cdot0=0$ to $a\cdot0+a\cdot0=a\cdot(0+0)$.  That's backwards.  He goes from $a\cdot0+a\cdot0=a\cdot(0+0)$ to something else, and from that something else eventually to $a\cdot0=0$.  You don't go from what you're trying to prove to what you already know.  You go in the other direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am reading pp 7 of Spivak's Calculus (3rd Edition) right now.

What he's trying to do is to prove: $$ a\cdot 0 = 0$$ using $$  a\cdot(b+c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c \tag{P9}$$ 
Let $b,c = 0$. We have: $$ a\cdot 0 = a\cdot (0+0) = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0. $$ By adding $(-a\cdot 0)$ to both sides of $ a\cdot 0 = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0 $ we get $$ a\cdot 0 + (-a\cdot 0) = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0 + (-a\cdot 0) $$ i.e. $$ 0 =  a\cdot 0.$$

Comment: Since I'm new to these parts I can't vote yet, but I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$a \centerdot 0 + a \centerdot 0 = a \centerdot (0+0) = a \centerdot 0$$ by distributivity.

Then we have that $$2(a\cdot 0) = a\cdot 0$$
which implies that $$a\cdot 0 =0$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $0=0+0$, then $a\cdot 0 = a\cdot (0+0)$.

Since $\cdot$ distributes over $+$, whenever we have $x\cdot (b+c)$, this is equal to $x\cdot b + x\cdot c$. Applying this to $a\cdot(0+0)$, we get
$a\cdot (0+0) = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0$.

So: 
$$\begin{align*}
a\cdot 0 + 0 &=a\cdot 0 &\text{(because }x+0=x\text{ for all }x\text{)}\\
&= a\cdot (0+0) &\text{(because }0=0+0\text{)}\\
&= a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0 &\text{(because }\cdot\text{ distributes over }+\text{)}
\end{align*}$$
So we have $a\cdot 0 + 0 = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0$. Cancelling one $a\cdot 0$ (or adding $-(a\cdot 0)$ to both sides) we conclude that $0=a\cdot 0$.

Comment: So, essentially, what Spivak is doing is starting from an expression whose value is 0 (the expression $a \cdot 0 + a \cdot 0$) and proving that it's equal to $a \cdot 0$?

Comment: @James Brewer: Spivak is starting from an expression which *happens* to evaluate to $0$, and *proving* that it does. I would have preferred if he had written the calculation in this order: $a\cdot 0=a\cdot(0+0)=a\cdot 0+a\cdot 0$ and therefore $\dots$.

Comment: @James: Spivak is starting from an expression, $a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0$, which he *doesn't know yet* evaluates to $0$ (he hasn't proven that $a\cdot 0$ is $0$ yet), and *proving* that it is equal to $a\cdot 0$. From *this*, he concludes that $a\cdot 0$ is $0$; and from *that* you can conclude that $a\cdot 0+a\cdot 0$ evaluates to $0$. But we don't know that $a\cdot 0+ a\cdot 0$ evauates to $0$ until we prove that $a\cdot 0$ does.

Comment: The room just started to spin ..

I think what I missed was that this proof is based off of a property previously listed in the text. See @J.D.'s (accepted) answer.

Answer (score 1):

That $a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0 = a\cdot (0+0)$ is just using the distributive law. (From here you get $a\cdot (0+0) = a\cdot 0$ and then you just subtract $a\cdot 0$ on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  He's not assuming $a \cdot 0 = 0$.  He's proving that.  So, you don't get from that to $a \cdot 0 + a \cdot 0 = a \cdot (0 + 0)$.  How you do get that last statement is the distributive property.  He then uses the property that 0 plus anything is that anything.  In particular, $0 + 0 = 0$.  Once you have that, we have $a \cdot 0 + a \cdot 0 = a \cdot 0$.  Now, we use the fact that every number has an additive inverse, so we can add that to both sides, which is the same as subtracting $a \cdot 0$ from both sides.  This leaves us with $a \cdot 0 = 0$.